# Mask position incorrect when I stop using a background image

Tags: html, css

Using http://jsfiddle.net/4UNuB/5/ as an example, the image has been set as background

```
.box1 {
    border: #999 2px solid;
    width: 180px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:  url(http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But, if I can't use a background image, and instead have an img src  within the div itself like this

```
<div class="box1"> 
    <a href="https://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/180x250"></a>
</div>
```

The mask no longer covers the image, instead sitting below it.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4UNuB/6/

But the mask is still being applied to the same place as before, so why does it move, and how to stop it moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Position Absolute and relative css for boxes.

Check The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adhershmnair/c81mnu5o/) here

```
  .box1 {
      border: #999 2px solid;
      width: 180px;
      height: 250px;
      /*background-image: url(http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png);*/
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: relative;
  }


 .black-box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put both in the same anchor and use positioning + z-index:

```css
.box1 {
  border: #999 2px solid;
  width: 180px;
  height: 250px;
  /*background-image: url(http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.black-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.black-box:hover {
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 110px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"> 
  <a href="http://placehold.it">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x250">
    <div class="black-box">
      <h2>View Details</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Also, I had to remove the `h2`'s margin.