# Responsive div with mask

Tags: html, css

Based on the mask idea on [Mask position incorrect when I stop using a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215234/mask-position-incorrect-when-i-stop-using-a-background-image/44215360#44215360) I tried a test on a horizontal, same height responsive div.

Result, the mask fails to expand to cover the div.

Html:

```
<div class="IndexBanners">
<div class="bannerimages effect first">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfaiXgY114U" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
<div class="black-box">
  <h2>Watch Video</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bannerimages effect">
<a href="https://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a>
<div class="black-box">
  <h2>View News</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.IndexBanners {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bannerimages {
    flex: 1 0 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.black-box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.8);
    width: 49%;
    height: 66%;
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.black-box:hover {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 23%;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
.IndexBanners {
    display: block;
}
.first {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}
.first iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

The fiddle for the test I set up is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3hekqxf7/
You'll see from the fiddle that there is literally only one size where the mask correctly covers the div. Given that I used percentage values for the mask I would have expected it to expand/shrink along with the div it is masking.

Question is, how on earth are you supposed to get a responsive mask on a responsive div?!

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/3hekqxf7/1/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!
I'll study your changes so I can learn for next time I want to do this.

If you add it as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: And for the person that marked it as close because it's unclear what I'm asking, perhaps you should try reading the whole post, specifically the last line that clearly says "how on earth are you supposed to get a responsive mask on a responsive div?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make the overlay responsive with the video parent is to use `position: relative` on the parent, then `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` on the overlay and it will conform to whatever shape the parent is.

```css
.IndexBanners {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.bannerimages {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.black-box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0.8);
    
    
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.black-box:hover {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 23%;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .IndexBanners {
    display: block;
  }
  .first {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
  }
  .first iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="IndexBanners">
  <div class="bannerimages effect first">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfaiXgY114U" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    <!--a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a-->
    <div class="black-box">
        <h2>Watch Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bannerimages effect">
    <a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a>
    <div class="black-box">
        <h2>View News</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Michael Coker, I've just discovered a flaw in that. When you hover over the embedded video you are not able to start playing it.
I'm assuming the div with the mask is sitting over the top of the video and thus preventing the click action on the video.

Comment: @StevePrice unfortunately that's a new problem. it existed in the old layout and isn't mentioned as something you wanted in this post. I looked at it but the fix isn't super obvious, or I would just help you out. See if you can figure it out, and if you can't, make a new post. Feel free to ping me if you do and I'll see if I can fix it.